# Screen orientation of an android application

Tags: android

Is it possible to write code on android manifest file that will automatically change screen orientation according to the device screen size?.

Answer (score 2):

May this help you:

Instead of fixing the orientation on the manifest, you could use `setRequestedOrientation`. On the `onCreate method` of each activity, check if you are on a tablet or smartphone and set the desired orientation.

Another option could be [Creating Multiple APKs for Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html), depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this cannot be done in the manifest. However, you can write some code to achieve this. Have a look at the `setRequestedOrientation` method of `Activity`. Details in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29).

However, this will probably not generate the best user experience.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Tablets have default orientation set to Landscape.
So this should automatically handled

Answer (score 0):

Write line given below in your defined Activity in Androidmanifest.xml,

```
 android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```